# PayPal REST API

Tags: php, paypal

I'm a bit confused. Sorry for this dumb question, just can't figure out the principles of how it works.

As I can see from the documentation on developer.paypal.com the REST API **doesn't** require to use any iframes on the website? So shows example from http://paypal.github.io/ (/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php in PHP SDK): just create approporite objects, make a call with credit card data (+billing info) and all is done; or redirect to PayPal for checking out using paypal account. And everything works good with sandbox accounts. As I understand, now I could enter my live credentials, add my bank account, get the new client_id and a secret key, change them in API calls and everything should work in the real environment, right?

We use PayPal Payments Advanced with an iframe (custom layout) to process payments with some strange SDK now and would like to migrate to this new API. But paypal's phone support says that this REST API is '*an iframe technology*', meaning that we should use iframes in any case. Where's the truth?

I thought that there were 3 payment solutions in PayPal - Standard, Advanced and Pro. Advanced allows you to use iframes, with a Pro you can use your own form and then just make an API call to proceed with a transaction. So I though that the REST API is the replacement for these solutions of the Classic API. Now I think I'm wrong.

In short.. I'm confused and would be very thankful if someone explains the point of these solutions and different APIs. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

yes your are correct with your understanding on the new REST APIs as in para 1 of making API calls to start accepting payments.

Apart from the samples that you have mentioned you may also want to check out the Reference Sample Applications that we have @ https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php

Please open issue @ GitHub if you run into issues. Thanks.

Comment: ... and you mean that I don't need to purchase any of "payment solutions", like Advanced or Pro? I.e. just accept my PP business account and charge users, collecting their billing information through my custom form?